# Find all $x,y$ for which $\nabla f$ forms an angle of $45°$ with the vector $(1,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f=x^2+y^2 \implies \nabla f=(2x,2y)$.

Find all $x,y$ for which $\nabla f$ forms an angle of $45°$ with the vector $(1,1)$.

So I thought of taking the dot product $2x+2y=\nabla f \cdot v=||\nabla f|\cdot||v|| \cos(45°)=4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

But the I couldn't solve $x+y=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, I know, from inspection that $x=-y$ is a solution, and I think there are no other solutions, but I don't know how to prove it.

Could you guys help me out?

E: Oh god, I see where my mistake was... I miscalculated $\cos(45°)$ as $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think there is an arithmetic error in the computation of the dot product.

Comment: what don't you square both sides?

Comment: I did, but I arrived at $-3x^2+2xy-3y^2=0$ which I didn't know how to solve.

Comment: Is it me or did you forget to take the root of that 4? Also, where has your $\cos(45)$ gone? Let me compute the RHS: $\|\nabla f\|\cdot\|v\|=\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{4}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So no, maybe you didn't forget to take the root, but you sure made a mistake somewhere. Unless you point out one of mine… So your equation becomes $x+y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which has trivial solutions for $x=0,y\geq0$ and $y=0,x\geq0$.

Comment: And $x=-y$ is definitely not a solution. Unless $x=0$ that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do the same thing as you, but I think that that your dot product is incorrect. If $v$ is the vector through $(1,1)$, then $v=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, so

$$
x+y=\nabla f \cdot v = ||\nabla f|| \cdot ||v|| \cos{(45^{o})}= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$

Square that and obtain

$$
(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2 \implies 2xy=0 \implies xy=0,
$$

so $x=0$ or $y=0$, which means that $(x,y)=(a,0)$ or $(x,y)=(0,b)$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}.$

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using cartesian co-ordinates, $(1,1)$ forms an angle of $45°$ with $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates.
So $\nabla f$ will form a $45°$ angle with $(1,1)$ if it lies on the positive x or y axis exclusively.

So $\nabla f = c \vec i$

or $\nabla f = c\vec j$

$c > 0$ is any scalar.

so $(c, 0)$ and $(0, c)$.

Comment: Doesn't it need to lie in the _positive_ axes? So $c\geq0$? If $c<0$, the angle will be 135˚…

Answer (score 0):

Clearly we can see that the vector $\hat x+\hat y$ makes a $45$ degree angle with both coordinate axes.  We expect solutions $x=0$ and $y=0$. To show this, we have the condition

$$\frac{\nabla f(x,y)}{|\nabla f(x,y)|} \cdot \frac{\hat x+\hat y}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\implies x+y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

which has solutions $x=0$ or $y=0$ as expected!

---

**Special Note:**

Note that since $\nabla f=2\hat xx+2\hat yy$, then $|\nabla f|=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and therefore we have that

$$\frac{\nabla f(x,y)}{|\nabla f(x,y)|} =\frac{\hat xx+\hat yy}{x^2+y^2} \tag{SN1}$$

Next, we note that the unit vector that points from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ is give by

$$\frac{\hat x+\hat y}{\sqrt{2}} \tag {SN2}$$

Taking the inner product of the right-hand sides of $(SN1)$ and $(SN2)$, we have

$$\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}(x^2+y^2)} \tag {SN3}$$

whereupon setting $(SN3)$ equal to $\cos \pi/4=\sqrt{2}/2$ gives

$$x+y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\implies xy=0$$

and we have either $x=0$ or $y=0$.